# Is there a way to output characters instead of numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

---

```
var numbers = [1, 3, 6, 1, 1];

var one = numbers.filter(function(number) {
  return number === 1;
});

var output ='1: '+one.length;
console.log(output);
```

---

"output" now is is '1: 3'

"desired output" '1: ***

Answer (score 8):

You can call `repeat` on a `*` character and pass it the number of times it should be repeated:

```js
var numbers = [1, 3, 6, 1, 1];

var one = numbers.filter(function(number) {
  return number === 1;
});

var output = '1: ' + '*'.repeat(one.length);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: As much as I like this answer it runs a "Object has no method 'repeat'" error :(

Comment: It's ES2015, so it should be supported in any reasonably modern environment. If you need to support obsolete browsers, add a polyfill for repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty array of same length of the filter array and fill the array with "*" and use `join` method of the array to get the string representation.

```js
var numbers = [1, 3, 6, 1, 1];
var one = numbers.filter(function(number) {
  return number === 1;
});
var output ='1: '+ Array.from({length: one.length}).fill("*").join("");
console.log(output);
```

Using `for of`  loop:

```js
var numbers = [1, 3, 6, 1, 1];
var one = numbers.filter(function(number) {
  return number === 1;
});


var output ='1: ';

for(const num of one) {
  output += "*";
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `map` and `join` along with template string.

```js
var numbers = [1, 3, 6, 1, 1];

var one = numbers.filter(number => number === 1);

var output =`1: ${one.map(() => '*').join('')}`;
console.log(output);
```

Comment: What if I can't call any library? such as jquery

Comment: @sandra, this is plain JS only es6 feature. No library.